# Convert docx to pdf in PHP

Tags: php, pdf, converters, docx, phpword

Right first a little background that will help put this all in focus.
I have several indd files (indesign). I can convert these to pdf and then to docx.

Using the phpword library I can then effectively do a mail merge and replace several areas of my document with text and one image.

I then want to convert that to a pdf, which I can then stitch several pdfs together for printing with ghostscript.

I have a word macro that I can execute just find via standard command line functions. If I try that same command line in php it just hangs.

I've tried various forms of that, using system, exec, passthru - using Psexec all either hang and then timeout, or don't work and skip through.

I've seen other examples using COM objects thing like this.
http://www.sitepoint.com/make-microsoft-word-documents-php/
all either hang or give me problems with the com object that I'm trying to make.

Am I trying for the impossible, or perhaps is there another way.
I've also given e-PDF Document Converter v2.1 a go but without success.

Currently I'm thinking that there is some permission thing going on but I'm really at a loss as to how to get around it or what to do.

I would maybe like to use either the libreoffice or the openoffice as they both seem to have command line tools but when I open the pdf or the doc file they display very poorly.

Any help.
Thanks
Richard

---

Update
Just thinking maybe I'll stitch the word documents together and then just allow the user to download it and then they can print it.
Job done easy!

But if there is a better way - I'm open to it.

---

Update 2 
On a windows platform

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like next ?

```
sudo apt-get install unoconv
doc2pdf respondus-docx-sample-file.docx
```

In php :

```
exec("doc2pdf \"" . $youPdfFile . "\"");
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention on a windows platform